# Symfony - How to deserialize with default values?

Tags: symfony, jms-serializer

I'm starting to learn Symfony 4.

I want to deserialize datas from json data. (I'm using JMSSerializer)

This is my context :
I have a Customer entity in src/App/Entity

```
class Customer {
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()     
     */
    private $name;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
     * @Assert\NotNull
     */
    private $comment;

    public function __construct() {
    $this->comment = "";
    }
}
```

I have a CustomerController controller in src/App/Controller

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/customers", name="customer_create")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();
        //Il faudrait valider les données avant de les mettre en base de données
        $customer = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($data, 'App\Entity\Customer', 'json');        

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response('', Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
}
```

I post a request for creating a customer with the following JSON data:

```
{"name":"Customer Lambda"}
```

but I have the following error

> NotNullConstraintViolationException
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO customers (id, name, comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [Resource id #99, "Customer Lambda", null]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment'
>   cannot be null

Is it possible to set a default value (empty string) for the comment field after deserialize? I was thinking that setting it in the Customer constructor will fix the issue but it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º Why are you trying to set empty string if you have defined comment as not nullable.

2º

This:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
private $comment = "";

public function __construct() {
}
```

Instead this:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 * @Assert\NotNull
 */
private $comment;

public function __construct() {
$this->comment = "";
}
```

Comment: I usually init the fields in the constructor. Just do simple and it works :-)
Actually I migrated an SQL Server database to MySQL and I didn't change some conditions as the not nullable which are not relevant...